# Convert latlng raw query to Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, raw

```
$markerResult = Accommodation::with('images')
    ->whereRaw($lat <= (`lat`+(0.00898315284 * $radius)))
    ->whereRaw($lat >= (`lat`-(0.00898315284 * $radius)))
    ->whereRaw($lng <= (`lng`+(0.00898315284 * $radius)))
    ->whereRaw($lng >= (`lng`-(0.00898315284 * $radius)))
    ->paginate(Config::get('global.pagination_records'));
return $markerResult;
```

Comment: $markerResult = Accommodation::with('images')
            ->whereRaw($lat <= (`lat` + (0.00898315284 * $radius)))
            ->whereRaw($lat >= (`lat` - (0.00898315284 * $radius)))
            ->whereRaw($lng <= (`lng` + (0.00898315284 * $radius)))
            ->whereRaw($lng >= (`lng` - (0.00898315284 * $radius)))
            ->paginate(Config::get('global.pagination_records'));
        return $markerResult;

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: You may find this approach valuable  https://aaronfrancis.com/2021/efficient-distance-querying-in-my-sql